# Load Balancing among Producers (devices) and Messaging Server ( Apache Qpid or RabbitMQ )

Tags: messaging, load-balancing, rabbitmq, qpid

Recently I started working on a project which require to implement Messaging and viable options are :  Apache Qpid or RabbitMq , My Task is like this :

**+A+ >>.[Millions Devices (Producers) -- Connected to -- Messaging Server (Clustered -- Qpid or RabbitMQ) ]   { LOAD BALANCING)**

And then

**+B+ >>.[Messaging Server (Clustered -- Qpid or RabbitMQ) -- Connected to -- GateWay Server (Clustered) ]**

And then

**+C+ >>.[GateWay Server (Clustered) -- Connected to -- Internet Explorers/Browsers (Consumers) ]**

See +A+ >>-- I need to use messaging usually for Load Balancing , and then later *Gateway Server* relay the produced data to Consumers (Browsers)

Means several queues are created inside Broker, by using some Load Balancing Algorithms. Producers ( Device Client) -- Send Message's Data to a specific queue, Delivery to a queue based on either Round Robin, or with other common Load Balancing Algos, Possibly it require Ack as well for guaranteed delivery, and then Consumers Picks the Messages from Queues and relayed further, All pretty standard stuff.

I studied basics of AMQP, and executed basic examples of both Qpid and RabbitMQ and then here are my questions :

- Is there a way , or some experiments or anything which can provide some thing to choose either RabbitMQ or Apache Qpid ?
- Is there any one who have ever worked on more or less similar requirement ? and he/she can provide any comments about it ? or some pointers before actually Implementing the algo , Implementation of Producers and Consumers ?
- My Overall requirement is related with Load Balancing, as my project expects millions of devices connected to Messaging server -- later Messaging data to be relayed and major confusion at this time to Select Apache Qpid or RabbitMQ, and to me both looks same

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get a look at this:

http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Message_Queue_Evaluation_Notes

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/17/load-balancing-a-rabbitmq-cluster/) is a solution that achieves efficient load-balancing in RabbitMQ.